# Wireless connection drops under heavy traffic load

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, router, wireless-adapter

Please read the whole thing before commenting if you would really like to help ! :)

I've had this problem for a very long time now and tried MANY different solution.

Here's the problem. My desktop computer is linked to my WiFi via a USB D-Link wireless adapter. It works fine, until I try to download large files via torrent, or simply download a lot, it crashes. My connection is lost.

Most of the time, I can just unplug it and plug it back in to make it work again. But sometimes, when I unplug and plug it back it my computer makes an unusual USB sound. It is pretty hard to describe a sound via words, but I think you know what I mean. Instead of doing the regular "tu-du" new device connected sounds, it makes this "tu-du-du" bad usb sound and I have to restart my computer to make it work again and it is extremely annoying.

So... here is what I have tried so far.

- Updating the adapter firmware
- Plug it in every available USB ports on my computer
- Ran a certain command line someone suggested that I cannot remember.

Recently tho, someone suggested to me a solution that makes a lot of sense. To go in device manager, and uncheck "Allow Windows to disable the device to save power" under the power management tab of the adapter itself.

I was very exited about this solution, only to arrive at home and find the "Power Management" tab is missing under my device and many others.

So yeah, this is everything I tried so far. I am all out of ideas. 
And before you ask, the reason my computer isn't directly plugged to the internet is a long story and even tho I know it is the best solution it is not possible in my current situation.

I am running Windows Vista (SP1).

**Edit:** To be more specific, what I really seems to be happening is that thing where "Windows shuts down the adapter to save power" because let's say I'm downloading at 1.8mb/s, the speed will gradually go down until it reaches 0 and the adapter dies. It's really like windows kills the adapter and won't allow it to work until I restart. Unfortunately, the Power Management tab is not there for a reason I don't understand.

So thank you so much for reading me and I can't wait for your suggestions.

Comment: What is the *router* you're connecting to?  I've seen bad firmware on either side cause this - if it's an old router you might find that simply flashing the firmware will fix it.

Comment: linksys wrt54g. Flashing the firmware means updating ? Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Also test the adapter on another PC... At least then you can be sure the hardware is fine.

Comment: Try a different wireless network, try a different wireless network adapter. Try the adapter on a different computer.

Comment: In addition to firmware for the router, make sure you have the latest drivers for the USB WiFi card, and make sure you've got the most recent Windows updates.

Comment: The adapter and Vista are both up to date.

Comment: Yes, "flashing the firmware" = updating.

Comment: Power Saving is (most likely) not your problem; it sounds like more and more corruption (slowing things down) until the connection finally drops.  Did this setup _ever_ work properly?

Comment: Yes, it used to work fine and never crash. Also, it used to automatically connect to my network when I start my computer, but now I have to manually connect each time I start my computer, even tho my network is set as default.

Comment: Is the adapter getting warm? The wireless chipset could be overheating as there is very little air flow in the USB key WIFI adapters.

Comment: Yes, it gets extremely hot.

Comment: You may want to try and hack together a temporary cooling solution and see if that helps.